# Android avoid notification to appear

Tags: android, filter, notifications

I'm trying to develop an app that avoid other apps notifications to show up in the notifications panel. Is this possible? To detect that an app is "creating" a notification and not show it.

Thanks

Comment: And why would you want to be interfering with the other apps the user has chosen to install on their phone, exactly...?

Comment: In that case, its better to hide StatusBar.

Answer (score 3):

While Notifying dev needs to pass a unique ID for their application.

public void notify (int id, Notification notification)

Parameters

id  An identifier for this notification unique within your application.

While canceling you need to pass that ID to cancel notification.
Even cancelAll(); will only cancel previous notification of that App only.
So it is impossible to remove other app notification from Stock Android.

Comment: What if someone built a database with the unique IDs of applications?

Comment: I didn't test by using some one others ID from other apps.